# unable to locate web element selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver

Hello I am a newbie with Selenium, I am trying to automate a scenario using webdriver framework: find a web element by its id. At the last step of the scenario, I am not able to locate a radio button and my code throws this error [Timeout Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrXgL.png)

This is my selenium code:

```
setTimeout(function(){

   driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('radRadioSub')), 24000, 'radRadioSub not located');

    if (pattern.comment.length > 0) {
        driver.findElement(By.name('remarksArea')).sendKeys(pattern.comment);
        console.log("Trying to update remarks area")
    }
    // Select Discard radio >> radRadioDis
    console.log("Trying to click on disegard/aprove")
    driver.findElement(By.id(actionToDo)).click().then(function() 
    {
        console.log('We clicked on the element' + actionToDo);
    });

    //  Send : >> btnSolveTaskToolbar
    driver.findElement(By.id('btnSolveTaskToolbar')).click().then(function() 
    {
        console.log('We clicked on the element btnSolveTaskToolbar');
    });

    },6000);
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('radRadioSub')), 24000,
>   'radRadioSub not located');

^ That is the line that is failing, and that is caused by an element with id *radRadioSub* not being found.  Look in your page source and find the correct ID.